# In swift2, UIPageviewController page curl animation hang/freeze on fast swipe

Tags: ios, swift, ios7, xcode6, swift2

I have implemented UIPageViewController using [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8bltsDG2ENQ)

In storyboard, i have define page view controller navigation **Vertical** and transition type **Page Curl**.

When i swipe pages very fast, the page curl animation get freeze. But if i do swipe slowly, everything works fine.

Can someone please guide me what could be the reason?

Comment: still unable to fix the issue :(

Comment: Improve performance, such as display large content after self.viewDidLoad. I am confronted with the same bug.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same problem. I resolved the issue by moving my code from `'viewDidLoad'` to `'viewDidAppear'`. Happy coding!